# JQuery DatePicker not changing language

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using JQuery DatePicker in my MVC project. I want to change language but not. I tried setDefaults, locale and custom month names but not working.

**DatePicker**

```
<script src="~/FrontEndJS/jquery-ui-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/FrontEndJS/datepicker-tr.js"></script>        

<script>
  $(document).ready (function()
    {
        //$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['tr']);
        $('#Tarih').datepicker(
               {
                   format: "dd/mm/yyyy",                 
                   language:'tr',               
                   startDate: new Date()

               }).on('dp.change', function (e) {
                   $("#Tarih").datepicker('destroy').datepicker($.datepicker.regional['tr']);
                   $(this).data('DateTimePicker').hide();
               });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="Tarih text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Tarih must be a date." data-val-required="Tarih alanı gereklidir." id="Tarih" name="Tarih" type="datetime" value="">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
<script>
  $(function ($) {
    $.fn.datepicker.dates['tr'] =
        {
            days: ["Pazar", "Pazartesi", "Salı", "Çarşamba", "Perşembe", "Cuma", "Cumartesi", "Pazar"],
            daysShort: ["Pz", "Pzt", "Sal", "Çrş", "Prş", "Cu", "Cts", "Pz"],
            daysMin: ["Pz", "Pzt", "Sa", "Çr", "Pr", "Cu", "Ct", "Pz"],
            months: ["Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık"],
            monthsShort: ["Oca", "Şub", "Mar", "Nis", "May", "Haz", "Tem", "Ağu", "Eyl", "Eki", "Kas", "Ara"],
            today: "Bugün",
            suffix: [],
            meridiem: []
        };
});

 $(function ($) {
        $("#Tarih").datepicker(
            {
                language: "tr",
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                startDate: new Date()
            });
    });
</script>
```